# small size scrollbar not able to Drag more content in Ubuntu chrome

Tags: html, css

[image]

here more line text available inside the box. but not able to drag. only able to inside mouse scroll or click arrow. not able to drag the scroll bar.

this work fine in windows system. this issue only in ubuntu browsers.

Comment: what version of chrome do you run on the ubuntu machine?

Comment: MY chrome version is 35.0.1916.153

Comment: Make sure you run an updated version, not sure if this will work but it's very much advisable

Comment: now i upgrade the chrome version. but same issue there. now chrome version is 38